# refractoring java bytecode

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to replace a certain class file with my own in an obfuscated jar. The original class file has methods named "new" and "null" so a quick decompile + compile doesn't work.
I tried compiling and using jbe to add new methods named "new" that relayed everything to "new_symbol" functions (with new_symbol beeing the decompiled version of the original "new" function).
This did not work. ("code segment has wrong length in class file")

Does anyone know of a way to refractor method names in class files? And if that isn't possible, a way to reliably create those "proxy functions"?
From google I learned that there are about 1000+ different backend library's but only jbe as fronted for bytecode editing?

**EDIT:**
Let me try to illustrate it.
Let's say that there is a jar file with a class that provides a function that logs everything you give it to a database.
I'd like to replace that class file with my own, and it should not only log everything to a database, but also print whatever data it gets to the command line.

The problem is, that class file was obfuscated and the obfuscator gave it public method names like "new"  or "null". If you try:

```
public class replacement{
public void new (string data){
...
}
}
```

And compile that, you get compilation errors.

My idea was to create this :

```
public class replacement{
public void newsymbol (string data){
...
}
}
```

And use a bytecode editor to create a function named "new" that calls "newsymbol" with the same arguments. (but I get "code segment wrong length" and other errors going down this route.

My question therefore could be better frased as "give me a way to intercept calls to a class file who's public methods are named "new" "null" "weird_unicode_symbols""....

Comment: Have you tried [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/)?

Comment: Java decompilers try to convert it to java source code but I can't recompile that source code because the public methods will never have the correct names to interface with the rest of that jar file.

They expect public methods named "new" but if you name a method "new" in a java file, you can't compile it because it goes against the java naming convention.

Comment: I hope you have noticed that I have provided a **link** to a program called _Java Decompiler_. Please attempt to decompile your original jar file using **this program** (not some other decompiler program) and report your result (whether the program has correctly decoded to valid method names instead of invalid method names like _new_).

Comment: no, didn't notice.
But I did use jdgui and as far as I know (or can find differently on that site) you can't edit the resulting decompile in-place.

The results are that the original public function "new" is replaced by "jd_field_new" and after recompiling the jar file crashes with a "method not found exception"

Comment: [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) provides a way to manipulate existing java byte code before actually loading a class. It provides ways to remove, add or modify existing methods or fields.

Comment: somewhat curious how you got this .jar file in the first place, if it has functions that wouldn't compile using javac. Which library is this?

Comment: It's a normal java application after beeing put through the ygaurd bytecode obfuscator (which works quite nicely, as you can see :p)

I'm going to try to give javassist a shot and see if I can get it to work (bcel failed on me). If it works out, I'll post a few details and a semi-howto as answer

Comment: How about a simple hex editor? Make sure that the method name is the same length as the intended length, and then just find-replace.

Comment: Would work, except the class is pretty complicated. Functions calling eachother and variables that are named the same way. It's pretty hard to find all references to eachother in a rather lenghty file.

Comment: actually, hex editing should work because the names of methods are only declared once. I'm going to have to check something first (getting another exception doing this) to know for sure.

Comment: Surprisingly, the easiest way to solve these illegal names produced by an obfuscator is to use an obfuscator. Just obfuscate the obfuscated code again but this time with different options, telling to produce valid identifiers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what turned out to be the best solution for me was to use a hex editor (as suggested by  user60561).

Apparantly, the name of every function and field is only saved once in the class file so if you use names with the same amount of bytes you can hexedit your way to victory.
For me it came down to replacing "new" by "abc" and every strange unicode character with a two-char sequence.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Scala allows you to use identifiers in names if you surround them by `` ` ``.

```
class f{
    def `new`():Int = {
        return 3
    }
}
```

[jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) output

```
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(bytes=/* snip */)
public class f
{
    public int jdMethod_new()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I assume that `jdMethod_` is prefixed in order to make the identifier valid. There is no `jdMethod_` when looking at the class file using a hex editor.

However, this does have a flaw when you need to use public fields; scalac never generates public fields, it always makes them private and creates accessors.

Comment: jdMethod_new is indeed what jd_gui uses to make the identifier valid. If I knew how to program in scala, I would've accepted this as solution.